# Using SUMIF function in combination with TEXT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with two columns: Date and Cost. The date is formatted in "XX/XX/XXXX". The cost is just a number value.

I have a second table where I have the dates listed out in month ("January", "February", "March"...) in columns.
What I would like to achieve is to do a SUMIF formula where the date matches the month in column.
This is what I have tried so far:

=SUMIF(B:B,TEXT(A:A,"MMMM"),D1)

In this case B:B = Cost , A:A = Date, D1 = "January".
However this didn't work.

Can you please advise.

Thank you

Comment: The answer would heavily depend on your data types. Are your values actual dates formatted? Or text values? In both tables

Comment: @JvdV          The A Column of "Date" is date formatted as mentioned (XX/XX/XXXX e.g. 11/09/2019). The D1 field is a text (/general) value of "January" as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `B:B` is your summing range, in that case,

Try

```
=SUMIF(TEXT(A:A,"MMMM"),D1,B:B)
```

> Syntax for **SUMIF**: `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`

or

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,TEXT(A:A,"MMMM"),D1)
```

> Syntax for **SUMIF**: `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this and it doesn't work. It's returning a generic error of 'There's a problem with this formula'.

Comment: @Revokez could you please edit your post to include some sample data from your Column A, B and D, and demonstrate the exptected output?